# How to get image URLs from inside an array of array using Simple JSON in unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

When I try to convert JSON array of urls into a list of string error occurs.The error is shown as:

```
Argument `#7' cannot convert `SimpleJSON.JSONNode' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

My Json Data handler class is given below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



[System.Serializable]
public class Handlepojo
{
public int astid;
public string prdname;
public int catid;
public string catname;
public string catdesc;
public int prdprice;

public List<string> Urls;


public Handlepojo(int assetid, string productname, int categid, string categoname, string categodesc, int productprice, List<string> Allurls)
{
    this.astid= assetid;
    this.prdname = productname;
    this.catid = categid;
    this.catname = categoname;
    this.catdesc = categodesc;
    this.prdprice = productprice;
    this.Urls = Allurls;


}


}
```

Below is how I add JSON data into a single list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < JNode.Count;i++)
    {

        Alldetails.Add(new Handlepojo(JNode[i]["id"], JNode[i]["product_name"], JNode[i]["product_category_id"], JNode[i]["product_category_name"],
        JNode[i]["product_description"], JNode[i]["product_price"],JNode[i]["product_images"]));
    }
```

My JSON value looks like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "product_name": "Wood Chair",
    "product_category_id": 3,
    "product_category_name": "Chair",
    "product_description": "Tough Hard wood",
    "product_price": "100",
    "product_images":
    [
        "http://test.com/testing/storage//productphotos/HYTh3zUYjQKuHavNSpjQ1xeUq7laeS1WwOKPOkpQ.jpeg",
        "http://test.com/testing/storage//productphotos/h01SOXObWmF07OCKesMFOacK4LRCpU8Rl14T6b1Z.jpeg",
        "http://test.com/testing///productphotos/cWQG7Xpkdhht1218xg5gPYaYDoi6pJPzt7MDhBqY.jpeg",
        "http://test.com/testing///productphotos/P64UvFr7vQidwSkKvGQjwebSCOAoHCXLfxijtPND.jpeg",
        "http://test.com/testing///productphotos/tKt8rf0FYHqYFlqMD3tqgTydqRYMFeKZBZiP7oMN.jpeg"
    ]
}
```

But in last line Jnode["product_images"] error shows

```
" cannot convert `SimpleJSON.JSONNode' expression to type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' . "
```

How to add them into into a single list? The way I have done is use another list and then add according to the assetid and corresponding URLs.Why cant I add a JSONarray in string into a list using SimpleJson?

Comment: you get image url by JNode[0]["product_images"][0]. loop your JNode[0]["product_images"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *product_images* field is more complex than the other types so you could try and deal with that first. I don't have experience with the *JNode* type/library you're using but I would expect you to be able to do something along the lines of:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < JNode.Count;i++)
    {

    List<string> Imagestring = new List<string>();
        // See what type we get from the relevant field

     for (int j = 0; j < JNode[i]["product_images"].Count;j++)
        {
            var imgeurls = JNode[i]["product_images"][j];
            Imagestring.Add(imgeurls.ToString());

        }

        // Note - the last item is now the array created above
        Alldetails.Add(new Handlepojo(JNode[i]["id"], JNode[i]["product_name"], JNode[i]["product_category_id"], JNode[i]["product_category_name"],
        JNode[i]["product_description"], JNode[i]["product_price"],Imagestring));
    }
```

Comment: ....the imageUrlNode returns only a single field ...in that how can I run foreach loop?

Comment: Got the concept from your code...edited according to my needs...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can add link to a string list using SimpleJSON.

```
    JSONNode jnode = JSON.Parse(data);
    JSONArray jLinks = jnode["product_images"].AsArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < jLinks.Count; i++)
    {
        links.Add(jLinks[i]);
    }
```

here "data" is your text format of your json file.